# How to fix error in Web Setup Wizard - Command "show" failed: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]

Tags: magento2, composer, repositories

This is the error when I click on Extension Manager:

```
Command "show" failed: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The
'https://repo.wyomind.com/packages.json' URL required authentication.
You must be using the interactive console to authenticate show [--all]
[-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self]
[-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [-l|--latest] [-o|--outdated]
[-m|--minor-only] [-D|--direct] [--strict] [-f|--format FORMAT] [--]
[<package>] [<version>]
```

https://snag.gy/ew2k1K.jpg

https://snag.gy/5qvThA.jpg

I have added the credentials to the Wyomind entry but I'm still getting this error. I'm pretty much stuck until I can fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure your [auth.json](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/http-basic-authentication.md) is setup properly and has correct file permissions so the Magento can read the file.

2) Try copy the auth.json into the root Magento directory.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution for me. I copied auth.json to the root directory. It had credentials for all our extension developer's repos. Once that was in root, I was able to proceed with upgrading Magento using the Admin Wizard.